# In a deck of $ 18 $ when $ 6 $ cards are dealt, what is the chance for at least one of the cards to be an $ A $ card ($ 3 $ $ A $ cards in the deck)?

Tags: probability, card-games

A bit of background (can skip this), I play this card game called Coup and in this game there are $ 6 $ types of characters with the Duke being the best card at the start of the game, there are $ 3 $ Dukes in the deck of $ 18 $. I usually play with $ 2 $ others and each person gets dealt $ 2 $ cards each, so $ 6 $ cards get dealt.

In the deck of $ 18 $ cards there are $ 6 $ types of cards (for simplicity just $ A,B,C,D,E,F $), for each type of card there are $ 3 $ identical cards. I want to know the probability of when dealt $ 6 $ cards at least one has an $ A $ on it. I tried to work this out with the binomial formula however this gave a very low chance of drawing $ 4 $ $ A $ cards which is impossible because there are only $ 3 $ $ A $ cards in the deck. Did I do something wrong? And how can prevent to make this mistake in the future?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ${18 \choose 6}$ ways to choose 6 cards from a deck of 18,
and ${15 \choose 6}$ ways to choose 6 cards from the 15 non-A cards.
So the chance of drawing at least one A-card is
$$1-\displaystyle\frac{{15 \choose 6}}{{18\choose 6}}.$$

Comment: I don’t agree. Some cards are identical. So picking A1,A2,B1 is same as A2, A3,B3.

Comment: @insipidintegrator $~$No, the cards are individual objects. $~$ $\rm A_1,A_2,B_1$ and $\rm A_2,A_3,B_3$ are two distinct outcomes in the event "two A and one B".